# Can't get OpenLayers vector layer to display (loaded by AJAX)

Tags: openlayers, geojson, ajax

I can't get the vector layer (loaded by AJAX to display). Spot my error?

I confirmed the GeoJSON returned by the server is correct.

```
var vectorLayer;

function showMap() {

    var fill = new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'rgba(255,0,0,1.)'
    });

    var stroke = new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.4)'
    });

    var circle = new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 6,
        fill: fill,
        stroke: stroke
    });

    var vectorStyle = new ol.style.Style({
        fill: fill,
        stroke: stroke,
        image: circle
    });

    vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        loader: loaderFunction,
        projection: 'EPSG:3857',
        //strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
    });

    vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: vectorSource,
        style: vectorStyle
    });


    var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.OSM()
            }),
            vectorLayer
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
            center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-85.781068, 43.023985]),
            zoom: 10
        })
    });
}

function loaderFunction(extent, resolution, projection) {

    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('FORM', 'report-mapservicebypop');
    fd.append('action', 'DOWNLOAD LAYER');
    fd.append('aplist', '##Fnumber#');
    fd.append('layer', 'bdccoverage');

    var geoJsonFormat = new ol.format.GeoJSON();

    $.ajax({
        data: fd,
        type: "POST",
        processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
        contentType: false,   // tell jQuery not to set contentType

        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            var features = geoJsonFormat.readFeatures(data, {});
            vectorSource.addFeatures(features);
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the json data:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
                                                                                
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "bxap": 1, "bxbatchid": "1658935447", "brandname": "BillMax Billing Solutions", "technology": 70, "maxdown": 25.000000, "maxup": 10.000000, "bizrescode": "X", "lowlatency": 0 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -85.785554600433755, 42.986793787262492 ], [ -85.776282949457794, 42.982635592279337 ], [ -85.77763155323612, 42.977522136286545 ], [ -85.784880298544593, 42.979264082833538 ], [ -85.785554600433755, 42.986793787262492 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "bxap": 1, "bxbatchid": "1658935447", "brandname": "BillMax Billing Solutions", "technology": 70, "maxdown": 25.000000, "maxup": 10.000000, "bizrescode": "X", "lowlatency": 0 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -85.785453735525209, 42.980429276576501 ], [ -85.775072168314665, 42.981700488887995 ], [ -85.774436562158911, 42.976456738103074 ], [ -85.786142308860605, 42.976138935025205 ], [ -85.785453735525209, 42.980429276576501 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "bxap": 1, "bxbatchid": "1658935447", "brandname": "BillMax Billing Solutions", "technology": 70, "maxdown": 25.000000, "maxup": 10.000000, "bizrescode": "X", "lowlatency": 0 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -85.809829468443525, 42.980612686611856 ], [ -85.80595223258085, 42.980949837556437 ], [ -85.804266477857951, 42.979432658305832 ], [ -85.804266477857951, 42.979432658305832 ], [ -85.802243572190463, 42.97903931553715 ], [ -85.802187380366362, 42.976061148860026 ], [ -85.8049969715712, 42.972071529349165 ], [ -85.81157141499051, 42.974263010488933 ], [ -85.809829468443525, 42.980612686611856 ] ] ] } }
]
}
```

Comment: Please add a sample from your GeoJSON data.

Answer (score 2):

Resolved... the problem is where the projections are defined. When using loader, the geojson reader needs this:

```
var features = geoJsonFormat.readFeatures(data, {                                                                      
    dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',   // data projection : long lat, WGS84
    featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857' // map projection  : web mercator
});
```